# how to implement big picture style push notification via gcm in cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

How to send big picture style push notification via gcm in cordova ? 
I am using pushplugin from cordova and as i have spend a huge amount of time trying to implement this, a step by step guide will be appreciated.

and also how can we calculate the payload size using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

The default Phonegap/Cordova push plugin does not have the necessary code to support big picture notifications.

It appears that there is a pull request that adds this feature here: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/498, however the pull request has not been accepted.

Comment: Is there any such fix for ngcordova `$PushPlugin`  or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267414/how-to-implement-big-picture-push-notifications-in-cordova-using-pushplugin)?